# Reading External XML in SOAP UI open Source and using it as Request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using SOAPUI FREE. My project requirement is to pick Request XML  (as we may have in hundreds) from a location and use it as it is as a request. Is it possible using any feature or Groovy Scripting in Free version

Comment: This is only possible using groovy script in the free version. For this you need to know groovy/java , iterate trough the directory and for every xml, create a TestStep, set the corresponding values and run the step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SOAP xml requests in some directory and you want to pick each file from there and create a new `TestStep` for each one, you can do the follow:

Create a new `TestCase` and add a new SOAP `TestStep` inside which will be used as a template to easily create the new ones, then add a a groovy `TestStep` an use the next code to create the new tests steps in the same `TestCase` (I put the comments in the code to explain how it works):

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase;
// get the SOAP TestStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("MyRequest");
// create the test step factory to use later
def testStepFactory = new WsdlTestRequestStepFactory();

// now get all the request from a specific location...

// your location
def directory = new File("C:/Temp/myRequests/")
// for each file in the directory
directory.eachFile{ file -> 
    // use file name as test step name 
    def testStepName = file.getName()
    // create the config
    def testStepConfig = testStepFactory.createConfig( tsTemplate.getTestRequest(), testStepName)
    // add the new testStep to TestCase
    def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 ) 
    // set the request from the file content
    newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(file.getText())   
};
```

I think that you're asking about the SOAP `TestStep` however note that this code is to create SOAP `TestStep` request, to create REST `TestStep` request or other kind of `TestStep` you must change the code related to the testStepFactory (`WsdlTestRequestStepFactory`).

Furthermore for me it's not clear in your question if you're asking about to create a test steps for each request or if you prefer to run all requests from a groovy script without create the test steps, if the second one is your intention you can use in groovy script the `apache-http-client` classes which are included in the SOAPUI to send the request from your directory.

Hope this helps,